# How to see full wallet address in etherscan.io Top Accounts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey, etherscan

I'm putting together a statistic of some ethereum addresses.

Using **etherscan.io** from the **Top Accounts** page: https://etherscan.io/accounts

But there the page displays the truncated addresses containing "..."

For example:

The **website** shows:

`0x000000...00000000` (truncated)

But **I need** to see the **entire address**:

`0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

**I need to see all full addresses on all pages.**

I know that it's possible to **edit** the site's display through the **Chrome** browser page setting **menu**.

There are chrome extensions to alter web pages using `user scripts` like `Greasemonkey`(for javascript) or `Stylish`(for css).

But I haven't found any scripts that solve this problem.

I didn't find anything internet that could help.

I have no knowledge about editing web code manually.

**It would be great if someone could** `create` **a** `user script` **for** `Greasemonkey` or `Stylish` **that could solve this.**

**Please someone help me to show full wallet address on all etherscan.io pages.**

I thank.

Comment: They offer an API, you should use the API rather than trying to parse the HTML

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether to answer this by developing an entire chrome extension for you like Stylish or just answer this from developer to developer.

**Disclaimer:**

> You should never paste code from an unknown source into your browser console.

With that said, you could use the following steps:

1. Go to https://etherscan.io/accounts
2. Right click on any white area of the page to open browser options
3. Select "Inspect Element", this will open the developer tools.
4. Look for and press the "Console" tab button.
5. Paste the following code and press enter.

   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table td a')).map(link => link.href && link.href.indexOf('https://etherscan.io/address/0x') === 0 && (link.innerHTML = link.href.substring(29))).filter(address => !!address)

The result should look like the following.
[Expanded ethereum addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTo0m.jpg)

Comment: Excellent!
Your code worked fine in my chrome.
Now I can see the full ethereum addresses on the page.
I appreciate your support.

But it's still tiring to edit each page manually.

Is there a way to create a user script with this code of yours to automatically use with Greasemonkey?
They are usually hosted at [link](https://openuserjs.org) or [link](https://greasyfork.org)